# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{1+na}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, pointwise-convergence

Let $g_n(x) = \dfrac{x^n}{1+nx}$ on $[0,1]$

I need to show that for every $a$ in $[0,1]$, $g_n(a)$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

It is pretty much clear for $a = 0$ and $1$.

But if I take $a$ to be in $(0,1)$ for example $a = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

I will have to show that $\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{1+n\frac{1}{2}}$ tends to $0$.

I can see that the numerator is tending to $0$ and denominator to $\infty$.

I even tried using L'Hospital Rule. It is becoming really lengthy.

Help, please

Comment: If numerator tends to zero, denominator to infinity, isn't that the same that the whole fraction tends to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $1+na \ge na$, $$\frac{a^n}{1+na} \le \frac{a^n}{na} =\frac{a^{n-1}}{n} \le \frac{1}{n} \to 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

For $a\in(0,1)$ we have
$$0\le g_n(a)\le a^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
Apply Sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers above have explained some elegant approaches to the problem, I would like to throw some light upon how to solve the sum using L's hospital rule, thus eliminating your doubt arising from what you have tried and was becoming  "really lengthy".....

$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{x^n}{1+xn}\right)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{\frac{d\left(x^n\right)}{dn}}{\frac{d\left(1+xn\right)}{dn}}\right)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x^n\ln x}{x}=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\ln x\left(x^{n-1}\right)$

Now, as x lies between 0 and 1, the limit equals zero...

---

There was no actual need of using L's hospital rule. Direct substitution would have given the answer easily.
If any further queries please do ask.....

---

P.S.-

L's hospital rule was absolutely unnecessary.I doubt whether we can use it,\ as 0/$\infty$ is not even an indeterminate form for x in between 0,1. But as the fraction would have been indeterminate if |x|>1, I suppose we could use L's hospital in this case...

---

Edit- Thanks to Martund, who not only rectified my silly error,but also  has helped eliminate any doubts. Here I would like to cite the main important points, which answer why L's hospital rule is applicable form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form):

- *the rule applies to situations in which the ratio of the derivatives has a finite or infinite limit, but not to situations in which that ratio fluctuates permanently as x gets closer and closer to c.*- In our case, the ratio doesn't fluctuate.
- *The requirement that the limit
  ${\displaystyle \lim _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}}\lim _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}$
  exists is essential*- in this case, both the limits exist.

Comment: You've got a nice name, @Aatmaj.

Comment: Thanks a lot 

Comment: As for your doubt whether L'Hopital rule is applicable, it is very well applicable, since the denominator diverges to infinity and the limit of the derivatives exist. But the point is, you should differentiate it with respect to $n$ instead of $x$, since $n$ is the running variable in the limit, not $x$. For all the limiting purposes, $x$ is just a constant.

Comment: So differentiating the numerator one gets $x^n\log x$ and differentiating the denominator one gets $x$. Now, $\log x$ comes out of the limit because it is a constant, and the remaining term $x^{n-1}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: You can read the second last paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form) as a reference for the fact that L'Hopital is applicable even for $\frac0\infty$ form if limit of the ratio of derivatives exists.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. it was Indeed a very silly one....

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: You're welcome @Aatmaj :)